# Need help converting a list into a dictionary and displaying it

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
file = open("Words.txt", "r")
freq = 0
lst = []

for line in file:
    line_word = line.lower().replace(',', '').replace('.', '').split(" ")
    for w in line_word:
        lst.append(w)


for words in last:
    if words in last:
        lst[words] = freq + 1
    else:
        lst[words] = 1


d = dict.fromkeys(words, freq)

print(d)
```

I'm trying to find the most occurred words in a text file and i want to convert the text file into a list and then into a dictionary with how much that word has occurred, i want the key to be the word and the value to be the number of times it occurred, im having trouble doing that and i have already tried using dict.from keys which i have seen on here before, which makes it into a dictionary but it doesn't have how many times it occurred.

Comment: You seem to have removed the line breaks and indendation from your code, rendering it nonsense. I suggest you [edit] your question to include valid code.

Comment: Just use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Comment: Your code has confused `last` and `lst`, but the right answer is what @MattDMo said.

Comment: @MattDMo can i print the 10 most common words with that or will it only print the entire dictionary with the number of occurrences?

Comment: Read the docs I linked to. An instance of the `Counter` class has the [`most_common(n)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) method, where `n` is the number you want. Results are returned as a list of tuples.

Comment: @MattDMo i got it thank you for the help I appreciate it, python is hard :(

Comment: Learning any programming language (especially your first one) can be difficult, but Python is very well documented. When you combine the large [standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/py-modindex.html) with all of the available [3rd-party modules](https://pypi.org), there's a very strong chance that if you're trying to do something, someone has done it before and made a tool for it. Of course, if you get stuck and googling isn't working, Stack Overflow is here :)

Comment: @MattDMo i do have one more question actually, can i take the elements of the tuple it gave me and print the individual word or number? like i have to print a table and put the word in a separate column then the number of times it occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you should be doing, from start to finish. I'll be making use of [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). I'll start by using the `with` [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#with-statement-context-managers) for opening the file. The sample file I'm using is the full text of *Alice in Wonderland* by Lewis Carroll from [Project Gutenburg](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/11/11-h/11-h.htm).

```
from collections import Counter

wordlist = []
with open("alice.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        wordlist += line.lower().replace(',', '').replace('.', '').strip().split()
# wordlist now contains all the words in the file

counts = Counter(wordlist)
# that's it, counting is done

rows = [f"{item[0]} repeated {item[1]} times" for item in counts.most_common(10)]
# creates a list of formatted strings from the 10 most common words in the word list

print("\n".join([row for row in rows]))
# join the individual strings with newline characters and print
```

This prints:

```
the repeated 1604 times
and repeated 785 times
to repeated 709 times
a repeated 614 times
she repeated 523 times
of repeated 493 times
said repeated 451 times
it repeated 416 times
alice repeated 351 times
in repeated 351 times
```